# Split String into factor using R

Tags: r

I sent out a fun questionnaire to our office to get some data for putting together a workflow for handling questionnaires in future. Some of the questions had textual input, and the responses were comma separated lists. The data were collected using a Google form, so they ended up in a spreadsheet. I'm linking directly to this spreadsheet to get the data into R so I'd prefer not to do any more pre-processing on the data than I have to.

Because the csv coming into R is comma separated too I swap the commas for pipes ('|').
I'd like to make bar charts out of the responses to questions like "what's your favorite piece of industrial design", but lots of people have said things like "iPhone, coke bottle". This comes up for me as a bar labeled with iPhone|coke bottle.

I'd like to split it up so that the iPhone part contributes to the iPhone bar etc.
In other languages I'd concatenate the whole list with a pipe separator, then split it again on the pipes then work with that new list. I'm stuck trying this approach in R; is it the right way to go or is there a more R way to do it?

```
a <- BVNdhData$Pets
b <- paste(a,collapse ="|")
c <- strsplit(b,"|",fixed=TRUE)
```

that all works, but leaves me with a *list* that I have no idea what to do with.

Comment: Could you please replace `BVNdhData$Pets` with something like your data? Maybe with 3-4 elements. What would you like c to become?

Comment: What language are you using? Oh, R is a language, sorry.

Comment: although your question is not completely clear you can use `unlist(strsplit(b,"|",fixed=TRUE)`  to get resultant elements after strsplit into a vector

Comment: Sebastian-c: I don't have any of my data with me, but it goes something like this `"cake|pie|sausage roll","scotch egg|pie"` and I'd like it to end up as `"cake","pie","sausage roll","scotch egg","pie"` which I could then feed into a bar chart (I'm using ggplot2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call `unlist()` on the results of `strsplit()` you get a single character vector with all of the components of your text:

```
text <- c("cake|pie|sausage roll", "scotch egg|pie")
x <- unlist(strsplit(text, "\\|"))
```

Use `table()` to tabulate the entries:

```
table(x)

x
        cake          pie sausage roll   scotch egg 
           1            2            1            1
```

Then coerce it to a data frame...

```
dat <- as.data.frame(table(x))
dat


             x Freq
1         cake    1
2          pie    2
3 sausage roll    1
4   scotch egg    1
```

... and plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x, Freq)) + geom_point()
```

[image]